# How to rewrite a new string to a specific location in a text file

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a text file with this content: abcdefghk

I want to write a text at position index of 3 with a new text: xyz

In such a way that I will have a new text file: abcxyzghk

How can I achieve this in native C++?

Comment: what have you tried? Basically you just read the file, create your new string and write a new file.

Comment: yes, but after writing text to the file, I want to replace a certain text at a specific location with ofstream

Comment: Simply use fread(), then use fseek() to move forward to desired location and finally fwrite()

Comment: If you are working with a `std::ofstream` then use [`seekp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) and [`write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)

Comment: @Blastfurnace But `seekp()` (or `fseek()`) to where?  If the file is opened in text mode, the only legal destinations (and the only ones likely to work as expected on platforms other than Unix) are `0` or a value returned from a precedant `tellg()`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I tried this one: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/ If I dont do this line: fputs ( "This is an apple." , pFile ); the output content will be not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `fseek` to position and rewrite. If you need to insert, you should use another approach. First, open for appending ("a+t"), set position, and write.

```
if (FILE* f = fopen("", "a+t"))
{
    const char* line = "xyz";
    const long int offset = 3;
    fseek(f, offset, SEEK_SET);
    fputs(line, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Note this is C++ code, and I put `FILE* f` under if scope to avoid accidental use `f` after `fclose`. Take care about possible I/O exceptions (`fseek` outside the EOF).

Comment: I think it should be: fopen("", "r+"))

Comment: Hmm... Good! But a+t and r+ is the only difference is a position for writing. Since we set it manually, this doesn't matter. All we need - don't rewrite a file.

Comment: a+t will set the position to the end of the file. r+ is for reading purpose and then seeking to a specific location. it works fine if i use r+. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In general, the only way to modify data in the middle of a text file is
by reading it, modifying the data in memory, and rewriting the entire
file (preferably to something with a different name, then deleting the
original and renaming the new file).  If the replacement text is exactly
the same length as the original text, however, and there are no new
lines in either,  you can read up to the position, then write at that
position.

Alternatively, you can open the file in binary mode, seek to an 
arbitrary position using `ostream::seekp`, and write there.  If the file
is to be treated as text otherwise, the same restrictions concerning new
lines apply in this case as well.  And in all cases, the replacement
data must have exactly the same length as the data it replaces.